# Android: App crashed on nougat devices

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-7.1-nougat

I have a sdk which has some native code. I am building the code into the shared libraries manually and copied those .so files to jniLibs folder. And I am using that sdk in an App. It was working fine with 5, 6 but with Nougat, it just got crashed every time I opened the App.

Note: I have updated the target version to 25 in the build.gradle file.

This is the error Log:

```
03-31 16:02:32.553 2050-2050/com.vinoth.sampleApp W/s.sampleApp: type=1400 audit(0.0:152): avc: denied { create } for uid=10156 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=netlink_kobject_uevent_socket permissive=0
03-31 16:02:32.553 2050-2050/com.vinoth.sampleApp W/s.sampleApp: type=1400 audit(0.0:153): avc: denied { read } for uid=10156 name="devices" dev="sysfs" ino=6380 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

                                                                                 [ 03-31 16:02:32.563   382:  382 W/         ]
                                                                          debuggerd: handling request: pid=2050 uid=10156 gid=10156 tid=2050
```

I have searched about this but ended up with no clue.

Someone please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What library? Too broad.

Comment: Start here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk

Comment: Its a customized UVCCamera Library. The app crashed with this log whenever I granted permission for any connected UVC camera. @Tatsuyuki Ishi

Comment: I have gone through it already, but I could not understand. @Egor

Comment: Native libraries you use are probably linking against non-NDK libraries, which will not work on Android N. These libraries should be fixed to bundle their dependencies, this will make them work on N.

Comment: Yes, To make it work, They told to add this line LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lMyLib. But I dont know which Android.mk file I should add this. Totally, I have 3 libraries which I am copying to jniLibs. So should I need to add this line 3 librraies?? @ Egor